# How can I parse JSON API data when there is no main key?

Tags: json, swift, api

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from an API, the JSON I have has no main key [JSONFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZYhn.png)

I have tested this with other API's which provide the main key and it is able to retrieve the data from them, is there a different way I should be approaching this? below is the code used to retrieve the API

```
    { func loadSongs(searchTerm: String, completion: @escaping(([Crime]) -> Void)) {
    dataTask?.cancel()
    guard let url = buildUrl(forTerm: searchTerm) else {
      completion([])
      return
    }
    
    dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
      guard let data = data else {
        completion([])
        return
      }
      
      if let crimeResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CrimeResponse.self, from: data) {
        completion(crimeResponse.crimes)
      }
    }
    dataTask?.resume()
  }
  
  

    private func buildUrl(forTerm searchTerm: String) -> URL? {
    guard !searchTerm.isEmpty else { return nil }
    
    let queryItems = [
      URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: searchTerm),
    ]
    var components = URLComponents(string: "https://data.police.uk/api/crime-categories")
    components?.queryItems = queryItems
    
    return components?.url
  }
}
```

and here are the structs for receiving the data:

```
struct CrimeResponse: Codable {
    let crimes: [Crime]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case crimes
    }
}

struct Crime: Codable {
    let url: String?
    let name : String?
   

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url = "url"
        case name = "name"
    
    }
}
```

Comment: you only have an array, just decode specifying [Crime].self which seems to be the type of data in your exemple.

Comment: No "main key": If there is no key it usually means it's an array. Notice that it's square brackets, and not curvy one. That's the JSON way of indicating it's an array or a dictionary, while in Swift, it's square brackets to declare them: `[String]` (array of String) vs `[String: Any]` (dictionary where keys are String).

Comment: @PtitXav and Larme Both thank you so much for your help, fixed it by adding []!!